# Django миграция данных SlugField

Tags: python, django

У меня поля в модели:

```
title = models.CharField(_(u"Название"), max_length=512)    
url = models.SlugField(max_length=150, default="Ne-zapolniaite-eto-pole")

def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(BlogBox, self).save()
    self.url = translit.slugify(self.title)
    super(BlogBox, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

url береться из title, как сделать так чтобы при наявности данных в базе поле SlugField автоматично делала миграцию данных (сейчас если создавать новий блог то все отлично работает а если в базе уже есть блоги то их  url ставиться за дефолтом "Ne-zapolniaite-eto-pole")

Answer (score 1):

В вашем примере поле `url` устанавливается в методе `save`, который не вызывается при миграции данных. Как я понимаю такая миграция это единичный случай, поэтому я вам рекомендую написать дада миграцию.

[Data Migrations django >= 1.7](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/migrations/#data-migrations)

[Data Migrations south](https://south.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial/part3.html#data-migrations)

Несколько замечаний, которые не касаются вашего вопроса.

1) Для реализации slug филда я бы посоветовал вам использовать AutoSlugField, который следит за изменениями указанного поля и автоматически создает slug. AutoSlugField реализован во мнохих библиотеках, я использую AutoSlugField из [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions). Так изменится ваш код:

```
title = models.CharField(_(u"Название"), max_length=512)
url = AutoSlugField(populate_from="title", max_length=150, default="Ne-zapolniaite-eto-pole")
```

2) Если вы решите продолжать использовать SlugField, то переопределение метода save не лучшее место для расширения логики сохранения объекта. Воспользуйтесь [сигналами](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/signals/). Вам отлично подойдет сигнал [pre_save](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/signals/#django.db.models.signals.pre_save). Вам нужно добавить такую функцию (часто ее добавляют в модель где находится ваша модель)

```
@receiver(pre_save, sender=BlogBox)
def my_handler(sender, **kwargs):
    blog_box = kwargs.get('instance')
    blog_box.url = translit.slugify(blog_box.title)
```

Comment: Спасибо за ответ я сдлал по примеру Django Migrations south  def                      forwards(self, orm):
    import random, sha, string
    for blog in orm.BlogBox.objects.all():
    blog.url = translit.slugify(blog.title)
    blog.save()                                                                                                     но не сработало я новичок может чтото не правильно понял

Comment: Странно. У вас отработала дата миграция? Если нет: проверте что название файла с вашей дата миграции начинается с номера, который больше на 1 прошлой миграции. Проверте что в таблице `south_migrationhistory ` нет миграций с большим или равным номером вашей дата миграции. Убедитесь что в вашей дата миграции есть поле `models` с такимже содержанием как и в прошлой миграции.

Comment: проверил все верно но поле url все равно не взяля значение из title срабативает только при добавлении блога а у существующих в базе блогов url так и остался дефолтным значением

Comment: data-миграция создаеться но код из def forward не исполняеться

Comment: я нашел ришение просто в сервисе где мы делаем запросы на блоги всем урл присваеваем тайтл транслит